# Requests module not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module

I'm trying to run my python code with the the requests module.

This is the code I use:

```
import requests

res = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json", params={"key": "rhcFvMg9fxSBPoN4TCb7hQ", "isbns": "9781632168146"})
print(res.json())
```

The following is the error that shows up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jonathankent/Downloads/project1/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

If anyone knows what could be causing this or what I could do to solve it I would be very appreciative.

Comment: That just means you don't have a module installed called "requests".  Depending on your installation of python, you might be able to just do `pip install requests`

Comment: I've tried doing that and it seems to install normally but when I try to run the file the same error shows up.

Comment: Are you installing it for python2 and then trying to use it in python3 or vice versa? Does `pip -V` agree with whatever Python version you're targeting (you've tagged both).

Comment: I think it should be targeting python three. When I type in pip -V the message that returns is the following: pip 20.1.1 from /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall the module before reinstalling it?

Comment: Yes I tried that and the same error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

[`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) module is not part of python built-in libraries so you have to install it yourself from the command line using pip:

```
pip install requests
```

Comment: I've tried doing that and it seems to install normally but when I try to run the file the same error shows up.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on MacOS try `pip3 install requests`

Comment: I just tried that now and I am still getting the same error

Comment: try sudo pip3 install requirements.txt